# What is the derivative of $ \sqrt{7}^x $?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What is the derivative of $ \sqrt{7}^x $ ?

Is it $$\ln(\sqrt{7})(\sqrt{7}^x) $$

or

$$ \sqrt{7}^x = 7^{\frac{x}{2}}? $$

Comment: The derivative of $a^x$ is $ln(a)a^x$ hence the first result

Comment: Aren't they the same ? I mean it make sense to manipulate it and do it like the second.

Comment: They should be the same. Your second one is missing $\frac{1}{2}$ from chain rule.

Answer (score 4):

Since $\sqrt{7}^x=\exp(x \log(\sqrt{7}))$ taking derivative we have $\sqrt{7}^x \log(\sqrt7)$ so your first answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods of solution are valid.

$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(7^{\frac{x}{2}}\right) = (\ln 7)*7^{\frac{x}{2}}*\dfrac{1}{2} = (\dfrac{1}{2}\ln 7)*\sqrt{7}^x = \ln (\sqrt{7}) \sqrt{7}^x$